# Can I simulate BLE device on iOS and set its name? (React Native)

Tags: ios, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-peripheral

Is there a way to simulate BLE device on iOS and set its name?

1. Is it achievable on iOS?
2. Is there any React Native library for that? (I found react-native-ble-peripheral library, but its README says, it works only on Android)

Comment: Just to clarify: You want your iOS device to behave like a BLE peripheral?

Comment: @M.Kotzjan Yes, at least to be visible as a device and have name/uuid etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research:

1. Yes, it is achievable on iOS.
2. Yes, there is React Native library for that: [react-native-peripheral](https://github.com/petrbela/react-native-peripheral)